# i am using a slider but when i code it. tooltip is not moving and hover is also not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I am using this website https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Highly-Customizable-Range-Slider-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Slider/ for slider and i am using Custom tick marks slider but the tooltip is not working i can't understand what went wrong with tooltip. i have copied the bootstrap-slider.css from dist folder css and bootstrap-slider.js from dist but still the tooltip is not working

```
//html code
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Comment</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <link href="css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

   
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ranges">
    <input id="test" type="text" data-slider-ticks="[0, 100, 200, 300, 400]" data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="30" data-slider-ticks-labels='["$0", "$100", "$200", "$300", "$400"]'/>
</div>
<!-- <script src="js/script.js"></script> -->

<script>
    $("#test").slider({
    ticks: [0, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ticks_labels: ['$0', '$100', '$200', '$300', '$400'],
    ticks_snap_bounds: 30
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try replace this:

[image]

> to this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js" integrity="sha512-f0VlzJbcEB6KiW8ZVtL+5HWPDyW1+nJEjguZ5IVnSQkvZbwBt2RfCBY0CBO1PsMAqxxrG4Di6TfsCPP3ZRwKpA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" integrity="sha512-3q8fi8M0VS+X/3n64Ndpp6Bit7oXSiyCnzmlx6IDBLGlY5euFySyJ46RUlqIVs0DPCGOypqP8IRk/EyPvU28mQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

If it's working, means the problem is the file's path.

[bootstrap-slider](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-slider)

Answer (score 0):

demo site slider version is 6.0.4 and it's outdated

recent version is 11 and it support only bootstrap 4

more information: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).